# MongoDB query over a large data-set is really slow

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, performance

im using mongoose to connect to a single instance of mongodb from a node.js application. both the app and the mongo server are on the same vnet so response times are not an issue.

the problem starts when trying to fetch the results of an indexed query, it takes almost forever (up to 20 min). when the query finally arrives back it may contain somewhere between 25k - 250k docs.

here's my collection stats:

```
doc count: 24354776
size: 59.9 GiB (64,308,640,625)
storage size: 18.9 GiB (20,301,250,560)
avg object size: 2.6 KiB (2,640)
indexes: 4
index size: 768.0 MiB (805,330,944)
```

the mongo server itself runs over a linux machine with the following:

```
CPUS: 4
RAM: 16gb
Disc type: SSD
Disc size: 1536gb
IOPS limit: 7500
Throughput limit: (MB/s) 250
```

in terms of tweaking the server to run mongodb as efficient as possible, i have the following:

```
store engine: wiredtiger
transparent_hugepage/enabled: [never]
transparent_hugepage/defrag: [never]
```

and finally here's what the query itself looks like: (the domain field is indexed)

```
async getEntriesFromDB(collection, domain) {
    return await collection.find({ domain }, { _id: 0, __v: 0 }, async function (err, res) { 
        if (err) {
            return await err;
        }
        return await res;
    });
}
```

Any leads will be greatly appreciated,
thanks for reading!

Comment: Which driver is this? This would not be valid code for the current core Nodejs driver. Also you cannot "await" a callback and only a Promise. At best this should be throwing errors, or it's not the core nodejs driver.

Comment: its node.js, you are right about awaiting the cb but the code works. however that's not the issue..

Comment: Buddy, the code does not work. It's not "taking forever" it's simply doing nothing. The callback response is a "cursor" and not a set of results you can "await". There are plenty of correct examples for you to follow.

Comment: correction, using mongoose

Comment: Okay, so now your question is *"I'm trying to pull 250K documents from my whole database into an in memory array. Why is this slow?"* Kind of self answering really. Nobody has a real world case for what you are asking, so the answer is your whole process is flawed here. Instead you should be "describing what you actually need to do" and then we can suggest more reasonable and performant courses of action.

Comment: thanks for answering, so im trying to get that large data set for parsing in node.js and returning an averaged result that will be saved to another collection

Comment: Homework - [MongoDB Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

Comment: oh, that looks like smth i definitely can work with, thanks a lot